# Regular expression in Notepadd++ match entire line

Tags: notepad++

I have a txt file with the following content:

```
Name:A
Start time: Thu, Mar 01 2021, 08:08:59 GMT

End time: Thu, Mar 01 2021, 08:18:49 GMT#"
Name:B
Start time: Thu, Mar 02 2021, 08:08:59 GMT

End time: Thu, Mar 03 2021, 08:18:49 GMT#"
```

I would like to keep only:

```
Name:A
Name:B
```

Therefore anything that starts with Start time/End time should disappear. Any ideas guys? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a regex to match `\R+(?:End|Start) time:.*` and replace with an empty string

Answer (score -1):

The solution is:

```
^.*(End time).*$
^.*(Start time).*$
```